# Get the running application name on Linux (without using argv[0]) in C++

Tags: c++, linux, api, exe

*There are many similar questions to this but I could not find one which exactly matches to what I need to know.*

It's a C++ application in Linux. I am in a deep nested function where I need to know the name of the this application instance. How can I do that?

Following are not the possible options:

1. Getcwd function return the directory name, and not the application
   name.
2. I cannot use argv[0] since I am not in the main function. Also, my
   main function does not access argv[0] and save it somewhere. Also, I
   am not the author of main function and I cannot change it.

Comment: Re, "I cannot use `argv`." Is that because you are not allowed to change the `main()` function? 'Cause if you're allowed to change the `main()` function, then it's simple for `main()` to stash the program name in a global variable that can be accessed by any other function.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, yes that's right. I am not allowed to change the main function.

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: `/proc/self/exe` is a symbolic link to the executable that is running in the process.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: There are multiple reasons due to which argv[0] solution is not feasible. 
1. The use of global variable would not be recommended by others.
2. It's a huge application and the call is too nested to add a new parameter at each level.
3. The call is inside the dll where I need to know the application name. So, it would be quite some work (a new function in dll to be called from app to stash the global value etc.)